# Open website option not working in Visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in my laptop (using windows 7 OS).

In Visual Studio, the open website option is not working.  The Web application and other projects are working fine but:

1. I am able to create new website, but I can't open a website.  The shortcut key for opening a website also doesn't work.
2. Also some *other* shortcut keys are also not working for example `ctrl+E+C` for comment, and others are not working.

What is causing these problems?

Comment: Try programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question....when you click in a website you have three views: code view and design view, and a mix of those two...try it with .aspx pages ;)

Comment: I am not able to open the web site.On click on the open web site nothing happen.

Comment: You should give it a try with the express version of Web Developer 2010....if this doesn't work either, then maybe your project has corrupted data....and if your project works on the dev express version, then your install of VS 2010 is corrupted or something.